# Why over/under-sampling could not help my model fitting?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, resampling, unbalanced-classes, oversampling

I fit random forest to my imbalanced dataset with minority class 1. I found that the AUC under the imbalanced data was better than that of re-sampled dataset (over/under sampling). Can someone help to put forward some theoretical explanation to justify this observation or please help to point out the underlying problem which caused this spurious output?

Comment: Why did you think balancing your data would imporve performance?

Comment: When I faced imbalanced data, I searched google and re-sampling was commonly suggested as a strategy for this situation. So presumably it should work somehow.

Comment: Perhaps your sampling technique is not maintaining the balance of the classes?